# Change source path in eclipse android project

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to change the source path in an eclipse android project (let's say to src/main/java)?

Answer (score 3):

On the `Package Explorer` view > right click > `Build Path` > `Configure Build Path` > Source tab is the place where you can add/edit/remove build paths for your project.

Comment: This works nicely in the eclipse environment, but the generated apk does not seem to be able to load the classes generated from the library project. I am getting NoClassDefFoundErrors when running the project in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to add two folders under the src directory named main/ and java/ then you should be able to do that by editing your build path in Eclipse.  If you right click your project in Eclipse it will bring you a context menu called Build Path and you should be able to set it to whatever you like.

I haven't tried it though, so I don't know for sure if the rest of the build scripts will have an issue mapping your activities, but you should be able to make a really simple project and try it out.

Let me know how it works out

DSC